# Cannot install iTunes on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

I cannot install iTunes on my PC (32bit) running Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I followed the commands:

```
sudo wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -   
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list      
sudo apt-get update      
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

I ran `PlayonLinux > Install a non-listed program > iTunesSetup.EXE` that failed with the error:
`iTunes requires that your computer is running Windows 7 or newer`.
Please help with the Windows 7 part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the WINE version of PlayOnLinux:

> - Install the version(s) you want to use: Tools > Manage Wine versions
> - Change the version used for a virtual drive: Configure button > (select virtual drive) > General tab > Wine version

Source: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-11075.html